# Sikuli: for loop/if else statement not working correctly

Tags: python, for-loop, sikuli

I have the following code in Sikuli that does copy and paste tasks. I want it to execute the actions inside "if not exists" when caption.png does not exist, but sometimes even if it doesn't, it is still trying to find it and returns an error that says "can't find caption.png".

```
     for idx in range(1, 77):
         if not exists("caption.png"):
              click("1406907972716.png")
              type(Key.PAGE_DOWN)        
              print "skip" + str(idx)
         else: 
              click("caption.png")
              type(Key.F2)
              type("a", KeyModifier.CTRL)
              type("c", KeyModifier.CTRL)
              click("CLICKBOX-4.PNG")
              click("BOX2-4.PNG")
              type("a", KeyModifier.CTRL)
              type(Key.DELETE)
              type("v", KeyModifier.CTRL)
              type(str(idx))
              type(Key.HOME)
              for i in range(25):
                  type(Key.DELETE)
              click("1406907972716.png")
              type(Key.PAGE_DOWN)
```

I tried the following and it worked, but something else does not work properly: sometimes it randomly jumps one idx. Can't figure out why:

```
    for idx in range(1, 77):
        if not exists("caption.png"):
            click("1406907972716.png")
            type(Key.PAGE_DOWN)        
            print "skip" + str(idx)
        else: 
            if exists("caption.png"):
                click("caption.png")
                type(Key.F2)
                type("a", KeyModifier.CTRL)
                type("c", KeyModifier.CTRL)
                click("CLICKBOX-4.PNG")
                click("BOX2-4.PNG")
                type("a", KeyModifier.CTRL)
                type(Key.DELETE)
                type("v", KeyModifier.CTRL)
                type(str(idx))
                type(Key.HOME)
                for i in range(25):
                    type(Key.DELETE)
                click("1406907972716.png")
                type(Key.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this in sikuli-IDE? The issue there is that there is not always a good traceback provided.

In your second example you seem to be skipping an index entirely probably because the caption is not found so nothing executes and it jumps to the next iteration. This is skipping the iteration with no output since all of the code is within the if block that re-checks for something that was already determined as existing.

I think the issue in the first part is you are not finding the match and then failing at the `click()` call (and the traceback doesn't end up helping). `exists()` returns a match, and also sets the value for `getLastMatch()`. You could try either setting a local variable with the match returned by `exists()` or in the else clause using `getLastMatch().click()` to click that region that was found (presumably your "caption.png").

You could also try specifying a wait time in the `exists()` line.

Lastly you could try setting each image as a pattern and use the similarity to pare the results down to one single match.

It is hard to give a definitive answer without a screen shot or info about what is on the screen and how many of the image could be on the screen. I can't comment yet, but if you could provide more information I can edit this answer to include a more specific answer.